# How to avoid 'Failed to load viewstate' exception when adding markup to a repeater?

Tags: c#, repeater, failed-to-load-viewstate

I have a custom control that inherits from Repeater.
I need to inject some markup around the items within the repeater.
Currently im looping around Repeater.Items (OnPreRender) and adding LiteralControls containing the markup. This works great except for when performing a postback, as it throws the 'Failed to load viewstate' exception.

1) Anyone have any better approach to this?
2) Or a way around the exception? maybe im adding the markup in a way that causes this?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the OnItemDataBound event instead of prerender.